# Laravel Hash::check returns false even if password is correct

Tags: laravel, hash

This works fine in my other Laravel projects but I have no idea why this isn't working on my new one. They are of the same version which is 7.3. Already tried `config:clear` and `cache:clear` but still no luck

```
public function Login(Request $request){
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;

    $userQ = User::where('username', $username);
    if ($userQ->exists()) {

        $user = $userQ->first();
        $hashed = $user->Password;

        if (Hash::check($password, $hashed)) {
            // It doesn't get to this part
            $response = array(
                "status" => 1,
                "message" => "Correct"
            );
        } else {
            $response = array(
                "status" => 0,
                "message" => "Invalid credentials"
            );
        }
    } else {
        $response = array(
            "status" => 0,
            "message" => "Username does not exist"
        );
    }

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

`$password` is a plain text. `$hashed` is the password I got from the database. This is my JQuery code:

```
var data = {
            "username": $("#username").val(),
            "password": $("#password").val()
        }
        console.log(data);

        Login(data).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.status) {
                $("#error-prompt").text(response.message);
            } else {

            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            
        });
```

Comment: The name ```$hashed = $user->Password``` is correct ? Maybe you are typo

Comment: @EncangCutbray nope, it's all correct. I added my JQuery code above

Comment: can you show how you are hashing the password for the user?

Comment: @lagbox It turns out that it's because I was putting in a blank password after all, there was something wrong with my jquery registration code that the password field was putting in blank data into the database

Answer (score 0):

Check if username is exists
`$userQ = User::where('username', $username)->first ()`

```
if($userQ) {
   if (Hash::check($password, $userQ->Password)) {
       // Password was check
    }
}
```

Comment: It does exist, the issue is that ```Hash::check``` is not working despite the correct credentials

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is here that you didng get the users:

change this:

```
 $userQ = User::where('username', $username);
```

to this:

```
 $userQ = User::where('username', $username)->first();
```

and you no longer need this line:

```
$user = $userQ->first();
```

and try again